# How to get value from website span class?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have the Russian website - https://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/contract/contractCard/common-info.html?reestrNumber=2183104497918000748

I want the value after the title called "Дата заключения контракта" that is 30.10.2018.

How do I extract the value and put it in an Excel cell?

I found the CSS selector of this value is `.container:nth-child(6) .section:nth-child(1) .section__info"`.

I have the following code:

```
Sub pupa()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim TxtRng As Range
Dim ie As Object
Dim data As String, ipt As String, tblsheet As Worksheet, gtrpt As String, lastrow As Integer, i As Integer
Set tblsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Таблица")
lastrow = tblsheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For n = 2 To lastrow
    i = n
    ipt = tblsheet.Cells(n, 1)
    Set ie = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "https://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/contract/contractCard/common-info.html?reestrNumber=" & ipt '
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        tblsheet.Cells(i, 2) = ie.document.getElementById("section__info").innerText
        .Quit
    End With    
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no id named `section__info`.  You may try the `getElementsByTagname("div")` method to get the collection of `div` tags.  Then, loop through the collection to find the element you want.

Comment: Yes, this is not the id, this is the span class, so that's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the title by using *getElementsByClassName("container")(7)* and then *getElementsByClassName("section__title")(0)*. With the *getElementsByClassName()* method you generate a node collection which includes every HTML element with the wanted CSS class. If you know which element of the node collection is the one you need, you can grab it by it's index.

The first index of a node collection is 0. In the HTML document of your page are 15 class elements with the CSS class *"container"*. In the 8th stands your needed value so it's the element with the index 7. After that you can use the grabbed element as base for the next use of *getElementsByClassName()*. There is only 1 element with the CSS class *"section__title"* in the grabbed container element so we use the index 0.

The trick is to keep circling the desired value until you can easily pick it up. In this case, there are 37 elements with the CSS class *"section__title"* throughout the document, so I would go via *"container"*.
(Code edited to grab the date)

```
'Needed Variables
Dim nodeContainer As Object
'Dim nodeTitle As Object
Dim nodeDate As Object
'...
'Your code
'...
'Grab the needed value with help of the above variables
Set nodeContainer = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("container")(7)
'Set nodeTitle = nodeContainer.getElementsByClassName("section__title")(0)
Set nodeDate = nodeContainer.getElementsByClassName("section__info")(0)
'tblsheet.Cells(n, 1) = Trim(nodeTitle.innertext)
tblsheet.Cells(n, 1) = Trim(nodeDate.innertext)
'...
'More of your code
```

To check how many elements with a specific CSS class are in the document you can use the *length* property of the node collection.

```
'Number of HTML elements with the CSS class "container"
Set nodeContainer = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("container")
MsgBox nodeContainer.Length

'Number of HTML elements with the CSS class "section__title"
Set nodeTitle = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("section__title")
MsgBox nodeTitle.Length
```

**Edit:** You can do the same without the variables in the following way. But I wouldn't do it because you can't intercept errors between the objects if needed:

```
tblsheet.Cells(i, 2) = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("container")(7).getElementsByClassName("section__info")(0)
```